# I can Ping facebook but browser keep showing time out error

Tags: networking, browser, facebook, timeout

it's been more than 4 weeks now that facebook occasionally go down for me, it start by saying that it can't connect to chat, then when i reload the page it tells me that i don't have internet, but i do, every other website works perfectly, i tried using almost all the available browsers, i also tried on other PC and even tried on a Macbook but still the same issue.

When i try "Ping www.facebook.com" on command prompt (win7) it works and most of the time when i type the facebook Ip on the browser it works either.

here is the things i tried so far to solve this problem !

- restart the router
- clear browser cookies/cache and remove all extensions except the very
  basics one
- Ipconfig /renew
- Ipconfig /release (it took time more than it needed so i canceled it 
  )

**Remark**
I can access facebook.com at any time using a proxy server from website like proxy4free.com, but it's annoying and facebook keep blocking my account and asking for new permission everytime i do that.

One last information, 99% of the time am using my laptop and connecting without a cable but i also tried using cable and there is no difference at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like this are caused by DNS of provider. Try set up Google DNS IP's for your connection.

Google DNS's

8.8.8.8

8.8.4.4

How to do this

http://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-7/

Comment: thank you, i managed to do the steps but only for ipV4, v6 say "invalid IPadress" also facebook worked now using the normal adress, but i can't be 100% sure that the problem is fixed because sometimes it works normally and sometimes it just stops. my question though, is this because of my internet provider ? or is it something related to my computer or router settings ? thanks

Comment: Set up only IPv4 addresses. Some of providers have sometimes problems with DNS. I can not say sure on 100%, but this type of problem is often caused by DNS. If you try it more, you can disable Google DNS and when FB will be unavailable try set Google DNS. If FB will work after that then you can be sure on 100% about error on provider side.

Comment: arghh >_< !!! it happened again with the google DNS enabled, even accessing it through ip doesn't work, only Ping work, and i noticed that the site Ip is different now

Comment: @alaslipknot: Try flushing the dns with ` ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah i tried that too, it "worked" but again it just get down at random moment, few of my friends said that they had the same issue too, maybe it's with our internet provider or maybe facebook is trying a new thing or something, i am going to re-select zorbon answer as the correct answer because so far that gave me the best result. thanks everyone